# How to select only string records with contains conditions using Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying iterate a sting[] and get only records which respects the condition "Contains".

I've been trying this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\" + ReportPushFile("fileToSend_1.txt")).Where(i => i.Contains("BILL"));
```

But this returns me all records again without no filtering. What's wrong?

```
class Program : Logger
{
    public static FTPclient Ftp = new FTPclient("ftp://smsftp.mobyt.it/", "C17053_004", "i7z0dx5b");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Sms> sms = new List<Sms>();
        sms.Add(new Sms() {  recipient = "+393664528452" });

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\" + ReportPushFile("fileToSend_1.txt")).Where(i => i.StartsWith("BILL"));

        // ...
    }

    public static string ReportPushFile(string NomeFile)
    {
        try
        {
            String LocalFileName = Ftp.ListDirectory("/reports/").Where(f => f.Contains(NomeFile)).OrderBy(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime).Max();
            Ftp.Download("/reports/" + LocalFileName, "c:\\temp\\" + LocalFileName, true);

            return LocalFileName;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `i.StartWith("Bill");`

Comment: The code you've got really *will* filter. I suspect you're diagnosing it incorrectly. Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I edited my code and added more details! I works perfectly until the line we discussed upon . I returns me all records and it respects my intention. Is the Linq line I posted that doesn't works as it should!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. Let's split it up and make the types explicit:

```
string path = "C:\\temp\\" + ReportPushFile("fileToSend_1.txt");

string[] readLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

IEnumerable<string> lines = readLines.Where(i => i.Contains("BILL"));
```

You can now set some debug points and verify that:

1. `readLines` contains a list of lines.
2. `lines` contains only those lines that have `BILL` in them.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Where do you see _all records_ (all lines)? In `readLines` or in `lines`, in my example? And how many elements does `readLines` contain, and how many items does `lines` contain?